# Why nested flatMap runs much longer than the same without nesting

Tags: java, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I'm using WebFlux's WebClient in order to retrieve data from remote Api.

There are about 1000 users, each of them have few posts, for each post there are multiple comments.

Here are the endpoints with appropriate methods:

```
GET /users
GET /users/{userId}/posts/{postId}/comments
```

```
Flux<User> getUsers() {
  return client
      .get()
      .uri("/users")
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(UserResponse.class)
      .flatMapIterable(UserResponse::getData);
}

Mono<Comment> getComments(Long userId, Long postId) {
  return client
      .get()
      .uri("/users/{userId}/posts/{postId}/comments", userId, postId)
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(CommentResponse.class)
      .map(CommentResponse::getData);
}
```

Just wandering why execute2() runs ~2 times longer than first one? Shouldn't they be the same or I'm missing something?

Because with nested flatMaps I can get all the data needed in the end of the execution, but with first one I should use Tuples to pass the data through all operators.

```
void execute1() {
  getUsers()
      .flatMap(user -> Flux.fromIterable(user.getPosts())
          .map(post -> Tuples.of(user, post)))
      .flatMap(tuple2 -> getComments(tuple2.getT1().getId(), tuple2.getT2().getId())
          .map(comment -> Tuples.of(tuple2.getT1(), tuple2.getT2(), comment)))
      .collectList()
      .block();
}

void execute2() {
  getUsers()
      .flatMap(user ->
          Flux.fromIterable(user.getPosts())
              .flatMap(post ->
                  getComments(user.getId(), post.getId())
                      .map(comment -> Tuples.of(user, post, comment))))
      .collectList()
      .block();
}
```

Response object:

```
@Data
class UserResponse {
  private List<User> data;
}

@Data
class User {
  private long id;
  private List<Post> posts;
}

@Data
class Post {
  private long id;
  private String title;
}

@Data
class CommentResponse {
  private Comment data;
}

@Data
class Comment {
  private long id;
  private String message;
}
```

Comment: A few questions about the unseen code. Does `user.getComments()` returns a list of posts (not comments, as the name suggests it would)? And is `getComments(user,post)` only supposed to return one comment (it's a Mono)?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, should have been user.getPosts() instead of getComments(). I have updated the code. And I think it could be related to http client and it's pool.. because if you do the same with mock data with some delays, without using webclient: execution time is the same